# iPhone - website is floating to the left

Tags: iphone, html, css, wordpress

I have this site here http://heyheyandco.com/ and I dont know what is wrong with it on an iPhone.

It looks fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE, iPad but not iPhone.

Its like everything is being floated to the left for some reason.

Here is some of my css of my site (btw its a wordpress site)

```
.site-content article {
margin-bottom: 72px;
margin-bottom: 5.142857143rem;
padding-bottom: 24px;
padding-bottom: 1.714285714rem;
word-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
padding-top: 15px;
}

.site-content {
float: left;
width: 65%;
margin: 1.714285714rem 0 0;
}
```

How do I find out what the problem is and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is it meant to be a responsive site or fixed?

Comment: Did you mean the header float to the left? Try putting some content in the space below the header (I guess that's where you'll put your main content eventually) and see if that floats to the left too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks fine on the iPhone apart from the header which is not mobile friendly. Could you describe more about your problem? Maybe a screenshot...

Try testing for the devices resolutions here http://mattkersley.com/responsive/ where you can play around with the developer tools as well and see problems that occur on different types of devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Use this in your html file...maybe you will get solution